# Multiple USB devices show up as one on Mac OS

Tags: macos, serial-port, embedded, port

I have a C099-F9P Application board that had two modules on connected through a FTDI and a USB-hub. When I run `ls /dev/tty*` I can see only one device show up as `tty.usbmodemXXXXX`.

When I use system profiler, under Hardware->USB I can see that there is a a "Hub" with multiple devices. See image below.

[Hub with three devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REQoe.png)

How do I access these usb devices individually when they only show up as one port?

I know on windows they are supposed to be 3 individual ports ([As per UBlox Documentation page 15](https://www.u-blox.com/en/docs/UBX-18055649)).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Most likely off-topic.  The question is about the behaviour of MacOS not about software development or coding - even if you are at some point going to write code for this board.  If the USB device code you have on the board is in fact your code, then the question may be valid, but without the code, it cannot really be answered.  I would suggest it is showing only devices in `/dev` for which it has a device driver, or the devices are there but not called `tty*`, but that makes it a general computing issue, not a development issue.

Comment: Are you still doing the hardware setup, or do you have some working code that can illustrate the problem?